# Не выводится текст

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем привет. Быстро распишу смысл программы. При вписании в строку enter текста help и нажатие на кнопку btn, в строку HowCanProgram должно вывестись слово "Текст". Текст не выводится. Буду благодарен, если напишите, где я допустил ошибку. Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
from time import sleep

def cmd():
    x = enter.get()
    enter.delete(0, END)
    if x == "help":
        HowCanProg.insert(0, "Текст")

window = Tk()
window.geometry("720x480")
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title("PyHelper")

HowCanProg = Entry(window, state="disabled")
HowCanProg.place(x = 0, y = 0, width=703, height=460)

enter = Entry(window)
enter.place(x = 20, y = 460, width=682)

scroll = Scrollbar(window)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

text = Label(window, text=">")
text.place(x = 3, y = 459)

btn = Button(window, text="Отправить", command=cmd)
btn.place(x = 633, y = 460, height=21)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В tkinter нельзя что-то записать в неактивное (disabled) текстовое поле. Перед выводом снимайте неактивность, потом возвращайте обратно:

```
def cmd():
    x = enter.get()
    enter.delete(0, END)
    if x == "help":
        HowCanProg.configure(state=NORMAL)
        HowCanProg.insert(0, "Текст")
        HowCanProg.configure(state=DISABLED)
```